# How can I get two values from this array

Tags: php, arrays, regex-group

```
Array
(
    [0] => {'error': None, 'result': {'asks': [['7.5197', '13231.93']], 'bids': [['7.5101', '0.9']]}}
)
```

I am getting an array answer like this from a web site with an api query.
In this array I want to get `7.5197` and `7.5101`. How can I get these two number in php? If you can help me I would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like json, have you considered useing `json_decode` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Response

```
   $str = "{'error': None, 'result': {'asks': [['7.5197', '13231.93']], 'bids': [['7.5101', '0.9']]}}";";
```

look like a json string, but isn't. With some substitutions it can be transformed into a valid json string.

```
$jsonStr = strtr($str, ["'" => '"', 'None' => '"None"']);
```

If there is already an array or an object in PHP, this steps can be omitted.

Now an object/array can be created with json_decode and the values can be accessed.

```
$obj = json_decode($jsonStr);

$valAsks = $obj->result->asks[0][0];  //"7.5197"
$valBids = $obj->result->bids[0][0];  //"7.5101"
```